# Cannot find element within iframe using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to locate elements within the iframe but got no luck.

I think because of my code cannot switch to the iframe and that's why I couldn't locate the elements within it.

Below is my code.

I have tried

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe')))
driver.find_element_by_name('applicant.name').send_keys('email')
```

I also tried this

```py
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_name('applicant.name').send_keys('email')
```

I tried look for xpath, id of the applicant.name but notthing work so far. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here the site:
https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Paratus-Partners-LLC/jobs/Full-Stack-Developer-7814e52be25090f3?from=iaBackPress&q=software%20developer&vjs=3

Comment: I cannot find applicant.name, can you share the html part your are looking at. Thanks

Comment: Where is applicant.name ? Help us navigate to it.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least **2 [iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)** in the page you're trying to automate:

[image]

Therefore you need to

1. Amend your [XPath Expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to uniquely identify first iframe like:

   ```
   parentIframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@id,'modal-iframe')]")))
   ```
2. Switch to first iframe

   ```
   driver.switch_to.frame(parentIframe)
   ```
3. Locate second iframe and switch to it

   ```
   childIframe =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'resumeapply')]")))
   driver.switch_to.frame(childIframe)
   ```
4. Once done you should be able to send text into the input fields.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. This work. Didn't know there are two iframes, and have no idea about using contains to locate the iframe. Thank again!

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with this question as well. Thank you very much.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574278/cannot-execute-if-else-statement-code-when-checking-button-is-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

There are some elements with the xpath `/html/body/iframe`

I was looking for the applicant.name and it was only to create after click on the postulate button.

I think that you have to check the xpath for the iframe, maybe something like this can work

```
"//iframe[contains(@src,'resumeapply')]"
```