# Cannot execute if else statement code when checking button is enabled

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check the button on indeed.com after you click apply job, but my code doesn't seem to work.
The first if to check if the continue button is enabled if not, then it will close the page, switch to the main window and apply for the next job. The if else inside the if statement to check if there another continue button, it will close the page and switch to main window if not click on apply button to finish and close the page then switch to main window.

Sorry, I cannot post pictures yet so I have to link them.

Here's the picture after you hit apply job
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FIGp.jpg

Here's the picture if there another continue button
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIEDb.jpg

Here's the picture if there's no continue button and only apply button https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuD09.jpg

And the last one https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpMBT.jpg

```py
# Click on continue button if there any             
if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="form-action-continue"]'))).is_enabled():
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="form-action-continue"]'))).click()
    if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="form-action-continue"]'))).is_enabled():
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.switch_to.window(main) 
    else:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="form-action-submit"]'))).click()
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.switch_to.window(main) 
#If no button close the window and switch to main window
else: 
    self.driver.close()
    self.driver.switch_to.window(main)
```

I also tried is_displayed() but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am wondering how you are calling isEnabled() on WebDriverWait. This will just wait for an element until it is located and won't return its WebElement. Hence, when you apply is enabled in line 1, 2 and 3, it throws an error.
First assign that element to one variable, and call that variable in WebDriverWait. Once element is located/ waited until element located by WebDriverWait, use click or is enabled methods using variable instead of WebDriverWait.